# Simple Carousel in React - How to register Scrolling to next Slide?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, react-hooks

This is a relatively simple problem, but I haven't been able to solve it. I have built the following carousel / slider:

```
const BlogPostCardSlider = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
  const activeSlideRef = useRef(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      //this is checking whether its the first render of the component. If it is, we dont want useEffect to run.
      firstRenderRef.current = false;
    } else if (activeSlideRef.current) {
      activeSlideRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'nearest',
        inline: 'nearest'
      });
    }
  }, [activeSlide]);

  const moveRight = () => {
    if (activeSlide + 1 >= children.length) {
      return children.length - 1;
    }
    return activeSlide + 1;
  };

  const moveLeft = () => {
    if (activeSlide - 1 <= 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return activeSlide - 1;
  };

  return (
    <div id="trap" tabIndex="0">
      <button onClick={() => setActiveSlide(moveLeft)}>PREV</button>

      {children.map((child, i) => {
        return (
          <SlideLink
            key={`slideLink-${i}`}
            isActive={activeSlide === i}
            onClick={e => {
              setActiveSlide(i);
            }}
          >
            {i + 1}
          </SlideLink>
        );
      })}

      <Wrapper
        onScroll={e => {
          let { width } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
          let { scrollLeft } = wrapperRef.current;

          if ((scrollLeft / width) % 1 === 0) {
            setActiveSlide(scrollLeft / width);
          }
        }}
        ref={wrapperRef}
      >
        {children.map((child, i) => {
          return (
            <Slide
              key={`slide-${i}`}
              ref={i === activeSlide ? activeSlideRef : null}
            >
              {child}
            </Slide>
          );
        })}
      </Wrapper>

      <button onClick={() => setActiveSlide(moveRight)}>NEXT</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogPostCardSlider;
```

It displays its children as Slides in a carousel. You can navigate the carousel by pressing the 'NEXT' or 'PREVIOUS' buttons. There is also a component that shows you what slide you're on (e.g.: `1 2 *3* 4` etc.). I call these the `SlideLink(s)`. Whenever the `activeSlide` updates, the SlideLink will update and highlight you the new current Slide.

Lastly, you can also navigate by scrolling. **And here's the problem**:

Whenever somebody scrolls, I am checking what slide they're on by doing some calculations:

```
onScroll={e => {
          let { width } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
          let { scrollLeft } = wrapperRef.current;

          if ((scrollLeft / width) % 1 === 0) {
            setActiveSlide(scrollLeft / width);
          }
        }}
```

...the result of this is that `setActiveSlide` **is only called once the slide completely in view.** This results in a laggy experience : the user has scrolled to the next slide, the next slide is in view, but the calculation is not completed yet (since it is only completed once the Slide is 100% in view), so the active SlideLink gets updated very late in the process.

How would I solve this? Is there some way to optimistically update this?

Comment: I think it would be useful if you provide a demo here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the calculations little bit so that when the slide is more than 50% in the view, set the active property to that one.

```
onScroll={e => {
    let { width } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    let { scrollLeft } = wrapperRef.current;
    setActiveSlide(Math.round(scrollLeft / width) + 1);
}}
```

**Example:**  Carousel with width: 800px, Total slides: 3. So, scrollLeft will vary from 0 to 1600

- From 0-400: Active slide = Math.round(scrollLeft / width) = 0th index
  (or first slide)
- From 400-1200: Active slide = 1st index (or second
  slide) since it is more in the view
- From 1200-1600:  Active slide =
  2nd index (or third slide) since it is more in the view

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight I thought this should be a quick fix. Turned out a bit more was necessary. I create a working example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-field-g78zb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The main point is that `setActiveSide` should not be called during the `onScroll` event, but rather when the user is done with scrolling. This is achieved in the example using the `onIdle` react hook.

Comment: the onScroll does not seem to be working, I click and drag left and right but nothing happens